# create a value service (module.value()) from a controller

Tags: angularjs

Sorry if this is a noob question : Can anyone tell me, why this works?

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').value('someConst', 'some value');

angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('wdget', ["someConst"] // all OK here, value service injected OK
      , function (c) {
        console.log(c)
      }
```

and this does not:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('widgetModule', ['myApp'])
     .controller('widgetCtrl', function () 
     {
         angular.module('myApp').value('someConst', 'some value');
     }

angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('wdget', ["someConst"]  // throws: Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider
      , function (c) {
        console.log(c)
      }
```

In this code segment, the last line, throws: *Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider*

Basically, the difference is that I am defining the value service *someConst* inside a controller of a different module. I am doing this, because I am actually setting the value service to a value available in this controller.

Comment: Use `angular.constant('SOME_CONST', {...});` and inject it with `.controller('widgetCtrl', function (SOME_CONST)`

Comment: same exact issue when I do angular.module('myApp').constant('someConst', 'some value');

Answer (score 0):

**NO**,You cannot declare a module inside  a controller. Instead you can defined the constant/value and alter it inside the controller.

Comment: I am not *declaring* a module inside a controller. it is declared above. I am just referencing it and adding a value service

Comment: no that wont work, as @aleksey mentioned above use dependency injection with constant

Comment: I am using dependancy injection. constant and value are almost the same. either way, both fail the same way ... any other ideas ?

Comment: the question is general - can you declare a value service inside a controller?